# Erro ao selecionar vários dados em login php

Tags: php, select, login

Tenho um *script* simples que faz com que um usuário do meu *site* possa visualizar seus dados em uma página, por exemplo: nome, email, idade, imagem. Veja o *script* abaixo:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title> Login de Usuário </title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="login.php">
<label>pnome:</label><input type="text" name="pnome" id="pnome"><br>
<label>nomec:</label><input type="text" name="nomec" id="nomec"><br>
<input type="submit" value="entrar" id="entrar" name="entrar"><br>
<a href="cadastro.html">Cadastre-se</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Esse é o PHP que faz o *login*:

```php
<?php 
$login = $_POST['pnome'];
$entrar = $_POST['entrar'];
$senha = md5($_POST['nomec']);
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','123');
$db = mysql_select_db('banco_cliente');
    if (isset($entrar)) {

        $verifica = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jogo WHERE pnome = '$pnome' AND nomec = '$nomec'") or die("erro ao selecionar");
            if (mysql_num_rows($verifica)<=0){
                echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Login e/ou senha incorretos');window.location.href='login.html';</script>";
                die();
            }else{
                setcookie("pnome",$pnome);
                header("Location:Pasta/comeng2.php");
                }
    }
?>
```

Essa é a página que vai mostrar os dados de *login* se ele logou:

```php
<?php
$pnome_cookie = $_COOKIE['pnome'];
    if(isset($pnome_cookie)){
        echo"Bem-Vindo, $pnome_cookie <br>";
        echo" $nomec_cookie <br>";
        echo" $img_cookie <br>";
        echo" $email_cookie <br>";
        echo" $idade_cookie <br>";
        echo"Essas informações <font color='red'>PODEM</font> ser  acessadas por você";
    }else{
        echo"Bem-Vindo, convidado <br>";
        echo"Essas informações <font color='red'>NÃO PODEM</font> ser acessadas por você";
        echo"<br><a href='login.html'>Faça Login</a> Para ler o conteúdo";
    }
?>
```

Então só me retorna a informação de bem vindo: "Fulano essas informações podem ser acessadas por você!" Mas as outras não mostra:

Essas não mostram no `echo`:

```
nomec
img
email
idade
```

Tentei alterar no `select` da tabela exemplo:

```php
$verifica = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jogo WHERE pnome = '$pnome' AND nomec = '$nomec' AND img = '$img' AND email = '$email' AND idade = '$idade'") or die("erro ao selecionar");
```

Mas dá erro. Como fazer para não dar erro e retornar todos os dados do usuário?

Comment: De onde vêm `$pnome` e `$nomec`?

Comment: de um formulario em html, que é usado para logar nao tem senha.

Comment: Adiciona o código do formulário na sua pergunta, pode estar errado os nomes

Comment: por favor adicione a mensagem de erro

Comment: nao existe mensagem de erro só nao esta me retornando esses dados:  nomec
img
email
idade

Answer (score 2):

Você capturou o pnome e o nomec em $login e $senha, tente mudar para essas variáveis no lugar.

Comment: mas o pnome mostra oque nao mostra é os outros dados exemplo nomec, img, email, idade, penso que isso esta no select do mysql.

Comment: então, veja ($login = $_POST['pnome'];) você transformou o que vem do form com POST na variável $login, mas no select colocou assim ($pnome). Confirme se o seu form HTML tem o method="POST".

Comment: conferi e tem sim mu dei e deu erro de syntax error. prece que tem que usar o nome login em pnome mesmo e senha em nomec

Comment: veja se eu usar assim ($login = $_POST['pnome'];) e no select ($pnome) funciona me retorna bem vindo, mas se eu fiser assim ($pnome = $_POST['pnome'];) e no select ($pnome)  da erro. e como fazer pras outras opçoes serem mostradas. sendo que no login só tem a opçao de pnome e nomec.

Comment: Poste o HTML do seu form por favor.

Comment: pronto coloquei o html pra voces da uma olhada.

Comment: Então Adailton, as outras informações estão no banco na tabela citada? Se estiverem você especifica elas na cláusula Select, no lugar do asterisco, separadas por virgula e captura elas após o select com mysql_fetch_row, conforme o exemplo da documentação do PHP [link]http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php[link].

Comment: esta sim na tabela sim, ata pensei que éra mais simples, mas tem um exemplinho pra dar uma ajudinha?